# How to cross compile OpenCV for ARM on Debian with dependencies installed for gnueabihf?

Tags: linux, opencv, cmake, cross-compiling, pkg-config

## What am I trying to achieve?

I'm trying to cross-compile OpenCV 4.5.2 for ARM (for a Raspberry Pi 4 - Raspberry OS Desktop) following these 2 guides:

1. [Cross compilation for ARM based Linux systems](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d0/d76/tutorial_arm_crosscompile_with_cmake.html)
2. [Cross compiling OpenCV 4 for Raspberry Pi and BeagleBone Black](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2018/12/18/cross-compile-opencv-raspberry-pi-raspbian/)

## What am I experiencing?

But I can see a lot of cmake warmings about failing to find some libs due to some pkg-config issue:

```
#19 39.61 -- Looking for dlerror in dl - found
#19 39.65 -- ADE: Download: v0.1.1f.zip
#19 40.28 -- OpenCV Python: during development append to PYTHONPATH: /opencv-4.5.2/platforms/linux/build/python_loader
#19 40.29 -- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29") 
#19 40.30 -- Checking for modules 'libavcodec;libavformat;libavutil;libswscale'
#19 40.33 --   Found libavcodec, version 58.35.100
#19 40.34 --   Found libavformat, version 58.20.100
#19 40.36 --   Found libavutil, version 56.22.100
#19 40.38 --   Found libswscale, version 5.3.100
#19 40.43 CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:882 (message):
#19 40.43   ocv_check_modules(FFMPEG): can't find library 'avcodec'.  Specify
#19 40.43   'pkgcfg_lib_FFMPEG_avcodec' manually
#19 40.43 Call Stack (most recent call first):
#19 40.43   modules/videoio/cmake/detect_ffmpeg.cmake:30 (ocv_check_modules)
#19 40.43   modules/videoio/cmake/init.cmake:7 (include)
#19 40.43   modules/videoio/cmake/init.cmake:18 (add_backend)
#19 40.43   cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:298 (include)
#19 40.43   cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:361 (_add_modules_1)
#19 40.43   modules/CMakeLists.txt:7 (ocv_glob_modules)
#19 40.43 
#19 40.43 
#19 40.43 CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:882 (message):
#19 40.43   ocv_check_modules(FFMPEG): can't find library 'avformat'.  Specify
#19 40.43   'pkgcfg_lib_FFMPEG_avformat' manually
#19 40.43 Call Stack (most recent call first):
#19 40.43   modules/videoio/cmake/detect_ffmpeg.cmake:30 (ocv_check_modules)
#19 40.43   modules/videoio/cmake/init.cmake:7 (include)
#19 40.43   modules/videoio/cmake/init.cmake:18 (add_backend)
#19 40.43   cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:298 (include)
#19 40.43   cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:361 (_add_modules_1)
#19 40.43   modules/CMakeLists.txt:7 (ocv_glob_modules)
```

Basically, I see similar warnings for all the libraries/dependencies that I have installed myself.

## What am I doing?

I run the compilation in a docker container based on debian:buster (latest) amd64.

And what I do is:

1. Install the dev env

```sh
GNU_HOST=arm-linux-gnueabihf
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get install -y autoconf \
    automake \
    build-essential \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gcc-$GNU_HOST \
    g++-$GNU_HOST \
    git \
    gnupg \
    jq \
    libssl-dev \
    libtool \
    meson \
    ninja-build \
    openssh-client \
    pipenv \
    pkg-config \
    python-dev \
    python-pip \
    python3-dev \
    python3-pip \
    unzip \
    wget
```

2. Enable armhf arch and install OpenCV deps for it:

```sh
apt-get update
apt-get -y upgrade
dpkg --add-architecture armhf
apt-get update
apt-get install -y gfortran-arm-linux-gnueabihf \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:armhf \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:armhf \
    libatlas-base-dev:armhf \
    libavcodec-dev:armhf \
    libavformat-dev:armhf \
    libdc1394-22-dev:armhf \
    libgstreamer1.0-dev:armhf \
    libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev:armhf \
    libgtk-3-dev:armhf \
    libjpeg-dev:armhf \
    libpng-dev:armhf \
    libpython2-dev:armhf \
    libpython3-dev:armhf \
    libswscale-dev:armhf \
    libtbb-dev:armhf \
    libtbb2:armhf \
    libtiff-dev:armhf \
    libv4l-dev:armhf \
    libxvidcore-dev:armhf \
    libx264-dev:armhf \
    openexr:armhf \
    python-numpy \
    python3-numpy
```

3. Set the pkg-config libdir

```sh
HOST_LIBS=/usr/lib

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=
export PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=$HOST_LIBS/$GNU_HOST/pkgconfig
```

4. Download OpenCV

```sh
OPENCV_VERSION=4.5.2
OPENCV_DIR=opencv-$OPENCV_VERSION

wget -O opencv.zip \
  --progress=bar:force:noscroll \
  https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/$OPENCV_VERSION.zip
unzip -q opencv.zip
wget -O opencv_contrib.zip \
  --progress=bar:force:noscroll \
  https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/archive/$OPENCV_VERSION.zip
unzip -q opencv_contrib.zip
```

5. Config, build and install OpenCV

```sh
CROSS_STAGING_PREFIX=/usr/$GNU_HOST/stage

pushd $OPENCV_DIR

OPENCV_BUILD_DIR=platforms/linux/build
mkdir -p $OPENCV_BUILD_DIR
pushd $OPENCV_BUILD_DIR

cmake -Wno-dev -Wno-deprecated \
  -G "Ninja" \
  -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../arm-gnueabi.toolchain.cmake \
  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$CROSS_STAGING_PREFIX \
  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
  -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../../../opencv_contrib-$OPENCV_VERSION/modules \
  -DOPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
  -DBUILD_PROTOBUF=OFF \
  -DPROTOBUF_UPDATE_FILES=ON \
  ../../..
ninja -j3
ninja install
```

## What do I need help with?

At this point, I've tried everything I could think of, but I cannot seem to find a way to make those warnings go away and make sure OpenCV uses the libs I've installed when compiling.

Basically, I tried setting `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` (to something like `/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf`), but that did not help, because when I use `apt-get install mylib:armhf` the libs/headers do not end up there, but in `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf`.

Then I tried setting `PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR` to the same value, without any luck as well.

The only thing that seems to work is to manually set each lib, e.g:

```
-DHAVE_JPEG=ON \
-DJPEG_LIBRARY=$HOST_LIBS/$GNU_HOST/libjpeg.so \
-DJPEG_INCLUDE_DIR=$HOST_INCLUDES \
```

But then I will need to do this for every single lib.

So my question is: is there any way to actually make cmake or pkg-config work in a multi-arch/cross-compilation env?

## Additional info

The cmake config I get at the end is:

```
#19 57.95 -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_PRIVATE_FIELD - Failed
#19 58.04 -- 
#19 58.04 -- General configuration for OpenCV 4.5.2 =====================================
#19 58.04 --   Version control:               unknown
#19 58.04 -- 
#19 58.05 --   Extra modules:
#19 58.06 --     Location (extra):            /opencv_contrib-4.5.2/modules
#19 58.06 --     Version control (extra):     unknown
#19 58.06 -- 
#19 58.06 --   Platform:
#19 58.06 --     Timestamp:                   2021-05-13T07:07:53Z
#19 58.07 --     Host:                        Linux 5.10.25-linuxkit x86_64
#19 58.07 --     Target:                      Linux 1 arm
#19 58.07 --     CMake:                       3.20.2
#19 58.07 --     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
#19 58.07 --     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
#19 58.07 --     Configuration:               Release
#19 58.07 -- 
#19 58.07 --   CPU/HW features:
#19 58.07 --     Baseline:
#19 58.07 --       requested:                 DETECT
#19 58.07 --       disabled:                  VFPV3 NEON
#19 58.07 -- 
#19 58.07 --   C/C++:
#19 58.07 --     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
#19 58.07 --     C++ standard:                11
#19 58.07 --     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++  (ver 8.3.0)
#19 58.07 --     C++ flags (Release):         -mthumb  -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
#19 58.07 --     C++ flags (Debug):           -mthumb  -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
#19 58.07 --     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
#19 58.07 --     C flags (Release):           -mthumb  -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
#19 58.07 --     C flags (Debug):             -mthumb  -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
#19 58.07 --     Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now   -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed  
#19 58.07 --     Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now   -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed  
#19 58.07 --     ccache:                      NO
#19 58.07 --     Precompiled headers:         NO
#19 58.09 --     Extra dependencies:          dl m pthread rt
#19 58.09 --     3rdparty dependencies:
#19 58.09 -- 
#19 58.09 --   OpenCV modules:
#19 58.10 --     To be built:                 aruco bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dnn_superres dpm face features2d flann freetype fuzzy gapi hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc intensity_transform line_descriptor mcc ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python2 python3 quality rapid reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking ts video videoio videostab wechat_qrcode xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
#19 58.10 --     Disabled:                    world
#19 58.10 --     Disabled by dependency:      -
#19 58.10 --     Unavailable:                 alphamat cnn_3dobj cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev cvv hdf java julia matlab ovis sfm viz
#19 58.10 --     Applications:                tests perf_tests apps
#19 58.10 --     Documentation:               NO
#19 58.10 --     Non-free algorithms:         YES
#19 58.10 -- 
#19 58.10 --   GUI: 
#19 58.10 --     GTK+:                        YES (ver 3.24.5)
#19 58.10 --       GThread :                  YES (ver 2.58.3)
#19 58.10 --       GtkGlExt:                  NO
#19 58.10 -- 
#19 58.10 --   Media I/O: 
#19 58.10 --     ZLib:                        /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/stage/lib/libz.so (ver 1.2.11)
#19 58.10 --     JPEG:                        libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.0.6-62)
#19 58.10 --     WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
#19 58.11 --     PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
#19 58.11 --     TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.2.0)
#19 58.11 --     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.4.0)
#19 58.11 --     HDR:                         YES
#19 58.11 --     SUNRASTER:                   YES
#19 58.11 --     PXM:                         YES
#19 58.11 --     PFM:                         YES
#19 58.11 -- 
#19 58.11 --   Video I/O:
#19 58.11 --     DC1394:                      YES (2.2.5)
#19 58.11 --     FFMPEG:                      YES
#19 58.11 --       avcodec:                   YES (58.35.100)
#19 58.11 --       avformat:                  YES (58.20.100)
#19 58.11 --       avutil:                    YES (56.22.100)
#19 58.11 --       swscale:                   YES (5.3.100)
#19 58.11 --       avresample:                NO
#19 58.11 --     GStreamer:                   YES (1.14.4)
#19 58.11 --     v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)
#19 58.11 -- 
#19 58.11 --   Parallel framework:            pthreads
#19 58.11 -- 
#19 58.11 --   Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)
#19 58.11 -- 
#19 58.11 --   Other third-party libraries:
#19 58.11 --     Lapack:                      NO
#19 58.11 --     Custom HAL:                  NO
#19 58.11 --     Protobuf:                    /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/stage/lib/libprotobuf.a (3.15.2)
#19 58.12 -- 
#19 58.12 --   OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
#19 58.12 --     Include path:                /opencv-4.5.2/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
#19 58.12 --     Link libraries:              Dynamic load
#19 58.12 -- 
#19 58.12 --   Python 2:
#19 58.12 --     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.16)
#19 58.12 --     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpython2.7.so
#19 58.12 --     numpy:                       /usr/lib/python2/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver undefined - cannot be probed because of the cross-compilation)
#19 58.12 --     install path:                lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2/python-2.7
#19 58.12 -- 
#19 58.12 --   Python 3:
#19 58.12 --     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.7.3)
#19 58.12 --     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpython3.7m.so
#19 58.12 --     numpy:                       /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver undefined - cannot be probed because of the cross-compilation)
#19 58.12 --     install path:                lib/python3.7/dist-packages/cv2/python-3.7
#19 58.12 -- 
#19 58.12 --   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
#19 58.12 -- 
#19 58.12 --   Install to:                    /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/stage
#19 58.12 -- -----------------------------------------------------------------
#19 58.12 -- 
#19 58.84 -- Configuring done
#19 59.97 -- Generating done
#19 60.02 -- Build files have been written to: /opencv-4.5.2/platforms/linux/build
```

So it somehow finds the Video I/O libs, even though cmake threw a lot of warnings about those. It did, though, not find the Media I/O libs (PNG, JPEG, etc) and GTK libs even though I have installed those as well.

You can find some more context on GitHub as well [opencv/opencv#20076](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/20076).